# Difference between const int* ptr[] and const int (*ptr)[]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

Is there any difference between

```
const int* ptr[5];
```

and

```
const int (*ptr)[5];
```

?

I am trying to point to a const 5*5 2D int array, but I am not sure of the best way to do it

Comment: The first form is conventional. Why would you use the second form?

Comment: If you just want a 5x5 array you can do `[5][5]` or `[5*5]` and use 2D emulation when looking up values.

Comment: When you say "5*5 2D int array" what do you mean by that? Like `int array[5][5];`? Or `int **array;`? Or `int array[25];`? Or something else?

Comment: I have a `const int array[5][5]` and I want to point to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const int* ptr[5];
```

This is an array of five elements, each element is a pointer to `const int`.

---

```
const int (*ptr)[5];
```

This is a pointer to an array of five elements, each element is a `const int`.